# What's the proper way to write a CSS selector with a class AND a pseudo class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Simple Question: what's the proper way to write a CSS selector with a class AND a pseudo class?

For example:

```
a.someclass:active {
  top:1px;
}
```

or

```
a:active.someclass {
  top:1px;
}
```

Which is correct? If possible, can you give me a source on this - such as a W3C reference? I tried to find it but alas I could not.

Comment: The selected answer to this question is wrong, as its own link shows

Comment: with :hover #2 is preferred (for ie6)

Comment: PS - thank you to all the stackoverflow nazi's for help with that. ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both correct, although the first one is more common.

Here's what's specified in the [CSS grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/grammar.html). You can see that the `.class` and `:pseudo` selectors are both allowed in the same places, along with `#id` and `[attrib=val]` selectors:

```
simple_selector
  : element_name [ HASH | class | attrib | pseudo ]*
  | [ HASH | class | attrib | pseudo ]+
  ;
class
  : '.' IDENT
  ;
pseudo
  : ':' [ IDENT | FUNCTION S* [IDENT S*]? ')' ]
  ;
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>First one is</strike> Both are right

[Selectors Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#w3cselgrammar)

Comment: FYI, When I clicked the link, I found this which seemed to support that the first one was right: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-link-pseudo-classes-link-and-visited

(see first example)

Answer (score 1):

Both should be ok, if I understand the [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-classes) correctly:

> Pseudo-classes are allowed in all sequences of simple selectors contained in a selector. Pseudo-classes are **allowed anywhere in sequences of simple selectors**, after the leading type selector or universal selector (possibly omitted).